# What is the meaning of "ahead" in this image?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

[image]

I think "in front of" or "before". What is the meaning of the sentence written in the image?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  It doesn't add anything to the words, and it isn't searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret it as "before", with the implication that the visit was deliberately made before the other visit.